# Error ORA-12541 TNS:No hay ningun listener

Tags: oracle

Tengo problemas al conectarme a la base de datos Oracle desde Visual Studio 2008, me aparece ese error, pero lo curioso es que al hacer el TEST de esta misma conexión en Origenes de datos odbc, la conexión resulta Exitosa. Revise el archivo tnsnames.ora y es el mismo que uso en otras maquinas y que funciona correctamente.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Haz **tnsping** y comprueba de qué ruta está obteniendo la conexión.
   Si te funciona el tnsping todo está configurado correctamente, es
   VisualStudio el que está utilizando otra conexión.
2. Si tnsping no te funciona: Puede ser porque tengas dos tnsnames, uno configurado correctamente y otro no y estés usando el que no es correcto,  compruébalo

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es comprobar la variable de sistema llamada ORACLE_SID, para esto seteala con set ORACLE_SID=tuSID y luego haz un tnsping.

Con los resultados te seguiremos ayudando

Comment: Gracias, hice lo que me dijiste y efectivamente tenia configurado un tsnames mal, entre a Sql developer en Herramientas> Preferencias>Base de Datos>Avanzada y busque el archivo en la ruta de Directorio Tsnames, curiosamente aunque actualicé "Todos" los tsnames de la máquina desde el explorador de Windows, ese no esta actualizado, agregue el nuevo HOST, guarde y listo :D..! Muchas Gracias :P

Comment: Me alegro mucho!